# Can one app run smoothly while having compiling errors in lower API level in Android?

Tags: java, android, api, compilation

This method in Android, **MotionEvent.getPointerCount ()**, has only been starting to use since API level 5.

However, my project is targeted to Android OS v2.2 (API level 8).

So I wonder what Android will do when run my project in a device with API level 4.

I have tried once, but it seemed no exception or crash, I do not know why?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int pointCount = event.getPointerCount();
    ...
    }
```

FYI, the above codes will cause compiling error when I set the API level of my project to 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android if you use a method that is not available you will get a [NoSuchMethodException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NoSuchMethodException.html).

You can look at [Backward Compatibility for Applications](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html) for more information.

So the answer to your question is: Yes, one app can run smoothly while having errors in a lower API.